# Parsing with Awesomium

Tags: parsing, xpath, awesomium

*the awesomium answering forums seem pretty much dead, so I'm reposting this here*

First of all, before starting to learn Awesomium I used the HtmlAgilityPack library for all my parsing needs, but the library is not being updated anymore and I decided to move to Awesomium. (so my approach is based on my experience with HAP)

I figured out how to parse lists of objects with Awesomium, but I can't figure out how to work with them. For example:

```
     public dynamic FindNodes(string xpath, dynamic node = null, WebView wv = null)
            {
                if (wv == null) wv = mainView;
                dynamic nodes = (JSObject)wv.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(String.Format("document.evaluate(\"{0}\", {1}, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)", xpath, "document")));
                int length = nodes.snapshotLength;
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(nodes.snapshotItem(i).innerText);
                }
                return nodes;
            }
```

The problems start after I return the nodes. I want to perform a series of searches for each node, so after returning them I decided that the following should work:

```
dynamic weakCounters = ap.FindNodes("//div[@id='weaklist']/ul/li");
            for (int i = 0; i < weakCounters.snapshotLength; i++)
            {
                ap.FindNodes("//h3[@class='black']", weakCounters.snapshotItem(i));
            }
```

But it did not. The part where I'm trying to get the length of the list and of course, if I try to get a snapshot of the item directly I get an error.

I understand, that I'm making a HUGE mistake somewhere. I just can't understand where.

Edit: Surprisingly if I do the following, everything seems fine, but it just doesn't look right to create a new variable everytime I need to access it (that's just bananas)

```
dynamic weakCounters = ap.FindNodes("//div[@id='weaklist']/ul/li");
            dynamic nodes = weakCounters;
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.snapshotLength; i++)
            {
```

Also, how can I pass the result (element) that I have extracted back to awesomium so that I could do a "subsearch" ?

Comment: Totally agree that the Awesomium Answers forum is pointless, since the Awesomium devs rarely respond.  Have you thought about [using Javascript  to do your parsing using an anonymous JS function with Awesomium](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21803284/1995977)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cross-posted answer from http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/4276/parsing-with-awesomium.html

> Why do you need Awesomium for HTML parsing? What's wrong with
>   HtmlAgilityPack?
>
> Download page with Awesomium (if that is why you need it), get HTML,
>   parse it with HtmlAgilityPack.
>
> Parsing like this should be very slow (if it return many elements).