# Loop through Awesomium Anchors & Click them

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, webbrowser-control, awesomium

Please take a look at these threads :

[Loop through Awesomium JSObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783735/loop-through-awesomium-jsobject)
http://firstbestanswer.com/question/2j7b6p/loop-awesomium-jsobject.html

Now for loop on all anchors on my web browser control i wrote the codes below :

```
   string js = @"(function() {
                                if(window.jQuery)
                                {
                                    alert('Yeah!');
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    alert('nope');
                                }
                                var elements = [];
                                $('a').each(function(){
                                    //alert($(this).attr('href'));
                                      elements.push($(this));
                                });
                                alert(elements);
                                return elements;
                               })();";
    JSValue result = webBrowser_extra.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(js);
    JSValue[] elements;

    if (result.IsNull)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(result + " : IsNull");
    }
    if (!result.IsArray)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(result + " : ! IsArray");
    }

    elements = (JSValue[])result;
    foreach (JSValue item in elements)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
           //Here i want to access href value of element and click on it, but how??????????
        }
    }
```

I want to loop all anchors in my page and get all href values and gather them in a list and click every element without using it's href.
How can i edit my codes for this purpose?